# How to generate a input tag above a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input tag and a link button. I want to click in the button and generate a input tag and an other link button is delete and click in the delete button to delete input tag. But when I click on the button generate input tag under the button. Now I want to generate input tag above the button. How can I do that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="mytext[]">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any code that we you have started with?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "prepend" instead of "append" to accomplish this. Check this snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
       
  $(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $(wrapper).prepend('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
            }
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;
        })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
  <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
```